# Выбор input с type=radio для отправки на эмэйл

Tags: php, ajax, html5, form

Добрый вечер.

Есть два инпута и нужно, чтобы на email приходил тот, что был выбран

html:

```
<input id="black" type="radio" name="color" data-name="Черный: "><label for="black" class="black"></label>
<input id="brown" type="radio" name="color"  data-name="Коричневый: "><label for="brown" class="brown"></label>
<div class="send_1"><input type="submit" value="Заказать сейчас" class="send"></div>
```

php:

```
$send = mail($toEmail,$them,$m_data,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$fromEmail");
```

Еще есть подключенный ajax.

Comment: Дык один и полетит. Это же type="radio". Только value задайте.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form action="send.php" method="POST">
<input id="black" type="radio" name="color" value="Черный" data-name="Черный: "><label for="black" class="black"></label>
<input id="brown" type="radio" name="color" value="Коричневый" data-name="Коричневый: "><label for="brown" class="brown"></label>
<div class="send_1">
<input type="submit" value="Заказать сейчас" class="send"></div>
</form>
```

в файле send.php

```html
$black = $_POST["color"];
$send = mail($toEmail,$them,$m_data, $black, "Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$fromEmail");
```